# How does ASP.NET Core determine path to login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am following this tutorial to ASP.NET Core

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6n9fhu94yhVkdrusLaQsfERmL_Jh4XmU

In parts 65 to 70 user registration and login is implemented from scratch using ASP.NET Core Identity `UserManager` and `SignInManager`. At some point, an Action inside the HomeController is decorated using the `[Authorize]` attribute. When pointing to that route in the browser, ASP.NET Core automagically redirects him to his custom login form under `AccountsController`'s `Login` action without him having registered this route as the login page.

How does ASP.NET Core Identity know where to find the login action?

---

Edit:

- He is using RazorViews
- Login Functionality is implemented in part 70
- Authorisation and the confusing redirect occurs in part 71

Comment: @LazZiya Yes, it does. According to the last comment, it appears that `/Account/Login` is the default unless overridden.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on razor pages, in 'Startup.cs' and in 'ConfigureServices' body write:

```
services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("page directory");
});
```

Comment: It's great to know that this can be set, but he is using RazorViews and does not define anything. He just creates Login() in AccountController and it somehow works, but I cannot find anything in the official documentation